# Add target synonym to makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have makefile with `modules` target. Without changing this target, I want to add `all` target which should redirect execution to existing `modules` target. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add dependency for target all to target modules like this:

```
all: modules
```